# my id won´t show up in my form

Tags: c#, json

i want to show up my id from the json url , but somehow it won´t show up

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - Width,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - Height);

    Label namelabel = new Label();
    namelabel.Location = new Point(13, 30);

    var json1 = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://dev.ibeaconlivinglab.com:1881/showemployeesbyhuurders?id=" + namelabel.Text);
    List <details> detailsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<details>>(json1);

    foreach (details dets in detailsList)
    {            
        namelabel.Text = dets.id;
        this.Controls.Add(namelabel);

    }
}
```

class

```
public class details
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int lID { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string wpUID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? I believe you are getting empty string when calling `WebClient().DownloadString(...`

Comment: is there any value in namelabel.Text or give a simple value

Comment: @shaminreza                           Label namelabel = new Label();
            namelabel.Location = new Point(13, 30);

Comment: You're adding nameLabel detailsList.Length number of times to the Controls collection, that looks fishy.

Comment: @RamblinRose what do you mean can you write an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `Label namelabel = new Label();` and two lines after trying to read its `namelabel.Text` and you use it as the ID in your request url. It is empty at that moment.

Also remember that some websites require to specify the UserAgent in http headers, in order to do so:

```
string jsonResult = "";
using (var wclient = new WebClient())
{
    wclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0";
    jsonResult = wclient.DownloadString("http://dev.ibeaconlivinglab.com:1881/showemployeesbyhuurders?id=" + someVarWithSomeID);
}
```

Comment: so what do I to add at the label to show my "ID" in the form to be exactly.

Comment: First of all, you have a problem with your request. It is returning nothing. Solve it by passing a value in the querystring `?id=`. Once that works you can show the ID in your form.

Comment: I have different ID's which means i have to if the id's equals to the json data then it will show up.

Comment: Sorry but it is still unclear to me how do you expect to have a value in this part of code: `...?id=" + namelabel.Text`, because as I said, `namelabel.Text` is empty at that point. Indeed that is the starting problem in your code, if you solve it you can continue from there or ask another question. On the other hand, if you have a code different of the one posted  here in your question, then edit it so we can be more precise to answer. Now this is all I can do.

Comment: where do i change it to so it actually will show up ?